# Navigate through hierarchy of contours found by FindContours method?

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv, contour

This must be simple for C++ developers using OpenCV directly. However what I'm using is Emgu (an OpenCV wrapper for .NET) and in the latest version we have the method `CvInvoke.FindContours` returning void, the output result is passed by parameter reference and is of type `VectorOfVectorOfPoint`.

Here is a simple call:

```
//outputResult is a VectorOfVectorOfPoint
CvInvoke.FindContours(inputImage, outputResult, null, RetrType.Tree, 
                      ChainApproxMethod.ChainApproxSimple);
```

For `RetrType.List` mode, we can just convert the result to some array of arrays and loop through all the contours easily. However here I would like to navigate through all the contours in a tree. I guess we must do something with native (unsafe) C++ code here with pointer (accessed via the `Ptr` property of the output result). But I wonder if there is a more .NET-friendly solution for this. And if even using pointer is the only solution, I still don't know how to delve into that `Ptr` to navigate through the contours tree.

The sample codes accompanied with the Emgu installation have a snippet using `CvInvoke.FindContourTree` instead (and that returns a `int[,]`).

Comment: Isn't hierarchy outputted in third parameter which you set to null? You can enumerate countours in exactly the same way, whether you use RetrType.List or Tree, to get hierarchy info, create new variable of type Mat and pass that as third parameter (which is now null).

Comment: @Evk yes, I did not realize that what I should pass in is at the third position, and even if I knew about that I would have not know what type it is. Now you let me know I should pass in a `Mat`. But I'm just tried finding more about that type and it does not seem to have any easy-to-recognize members to help navigate through the tree. If possible please give me some example code in your answer. That would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

To obtain the hierarchy of the contours, you must first pass a `Mat` object to the function:

```
Mat hierarchy = new Mat() ;
CvInvoke.FindContours(inputImage, outputResult, hierarchy, RetrType.Tree, 
                  ChainApproxMethod.ChainApproxSimple);
```

Then you can use the `hierarchy` object as follows (see [here](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d9/d8b/tutorial_py_contours_hierarchy.html#gsc.tab=0) for more details in Python OpenCV) :

`hierarchy` will be a `Mat` object of size 1 x size of `outputResult` x 4.
So for the contour with index `i`:

- `hierachy[0,i,0]` is the index of the next contour at the same hierarchy level (with the same parent) or - 1 if it doesn't exist
- `hierachy[0,i,1]` is the index of the previous contour at the same hierarchy level or - 1 if it doesn't exist
- `hierachy[0,i,2]` is the index of the child of contour `i` or - 1 if it doesn't exist
- `hierachy[0,i,3]` is the index of the parent of contour `i` or - 1 if it doesn't exist

That's how you use the hierarchy object.

The contours themselves are accessed through the `outputResult` object by using their indices.

Comment: Are you sure `Mat` has any indexer accepting 3 arguments? I've tried declaring a simple variable of `Mat` and writing something like this `m[0,0,0]` causes some design time error and of course it cannot even compile. What you suggested may be valid and work in Python, but here I'm asking in C#. Thanks!

Comment: Did you try `m.Data[0,0,0]` ? I can't test it with C# but some answers online seem to say that's possible.

Comment: `m.Data` is an `Array` which may have various dimension (rank), so it probably has a rank of `3` but then we need to use the method `GetValue` instead (`Array` also does not have any Indexer accepting 3 arguments). However I've tried my code and `m.Data` is actually `null` which is impossible if a tree structure should be achieved, that means `m.Data` is not where to pull the tree data. This `Map` is itself fairly complicated to me, it is some kind of general purpose class, so it's hard to know how to use it in this specific scenario.

Comment: @Hopeless  Then a solution would be to copy the data into an array using `hierarchy.CopyTo`method as explained in [this discussion](http://www.emgu.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6333). But then, you will have to adapt your indices to access the right elements. Could you try to copy the data to see if that works ?